# Rails2 Routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 2 application, I found a security bug in routing. I am using Rails 2.3.8. Here is my implementation:

```
# routes.rb
map.connect 'sampleview', :controller => 'sample', :action => 'view'
```

For some condition, the URL in my comes like http://example.com/sampleview?view_url=http://test.com?s=2&code=15

In this case I have gone to test.com (this test.com is another domain which I have shown in my app) and the pages are placed in iframe tag.

The problem is suppose if I frame url:

```
http://example.com/sampleview?view_url=http://www.google.com
```

The Google landing page was placed in the iframe tag with in my application. This is not good.

If URL http://example.com/sampleview?view_url=http://www.google.com contains other than that test.com. I have to raise the message to user. This is not valid URL here.

How can modify my routes.rb to support this or any other solution. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do this in Rails 3.2 as the constraint option on route does not exists. I would suggest you to implement this in the controller, eventually with a `before_filter`. You can place it in the `ApplicationController` if you have to share it between different controllers.

UPDATE: add example

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_view_url

  private

  def check_view_url
    if params[:view_url] && params[:view_url] !~ %r{^http://test.com}
      raise "Trying to access invalid website"
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: So you said, I have validate the URL name in controller itself like implementing before_filter should check the URL name? Is it rite?

Comment: Yes, please see the example I just added to my answer. You can adapt the regexp to match your need as well as the location where you define `check_view_url` and define the `before_filter`.

Comment: Thanks Adrien Coquio. It really save my time lot